# Spring mvc form:select tag - put reference to object at VALUE

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Is it possible to put a reference to object at `VALUE=""`? I want to return the whole object, not only field.

I added transient field `int temporary` in this object to save $`{ tempDepartment.id}` and read it from this `ObjectDAO` with session and then finally add Department to object.

I think there is a better way, but my knowledge is not enough.

[image: code:]